# Does the graph-node re-sync all blocks every time it gets restarted?

Tags: blockchain, database, docker, the-graph, subgraph

I am running an EC2 instance with `graph-node`, using `docker`.

Let's assume that I have a list of smart contracts that I want my subgraph to track and, at some point, that list gets updated; so I have to re-compile my subgraph and re-deploy it.

Under this scenario: is my node going to sync all blocks from the blockchain again? Even the ones I already have synced on my database? Or is it going to disregard the blocks that do not have any change in terms of the contracts I am tracking?

Basically I want to understand if the information I already have on my database is going to be replaced by new information or if the graph is "smart enough" to keep the information that has not changed (without compromising the performance).